# Overriding ilike method by like in grails createCriteria

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

In my application we have collation set for MYSQL in such a way that "like" condition is always case in-sensitive. So, we need conditionally ilike to replaced with like at run time based on config. (Because, in future database might be Oracle or some other DB.Want to handle this at application level.)

Tried one solution which does not works. I want this at application level:

```
 grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.metaClass.ilike={String propertyName, Object propertyValue->
    println "-------------------${propertyName}, ${propertyValue}"
    delegate.like(propertyName, propertyValue)
   }

    def criteria= MyDomain.createCriteria()

    criteria.list(){
        ilike('name','%dasda%')
    }
```

So, Any other way would also be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,

Anuj Aneja

Comment: You're trying to change `ilike` so it is case-sensitive? Why not just use `like`?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, i can do that. but i need a switch to turn off/on. I do not want make a lot of change.

Comment: You know that you can use condition inside the createCriteria? why not just decide which one to use based on your config. it will be simple if statement.

Comment: Well, i would prefer to use a neat solution via meta programming as i mentioned above.

Comment: Sure, but neat solutions sometimes are the simplest ones.